# How to use a common component with same logic in multi containers?

Tags: reactjs

There's a common component in my App.

And I have 2 containers hold 2 pages, while they r sharing the common component.

So what should I do to code the logic of the common component? Both copy in the 2 containers?

Codes below:

#### Component C:

```
const C = props => {
    return <div onClick={props.onLikeClick}>Like</div>
}
```

#### Container A:

```
class A extends Component {
    onLikeClick() {
        // data request ...
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <C
                 onLikeClick={this.onLikeClick.bind(this)}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

#### Container B:

```
class B extends Component {
    onLikeClick() {
        // data request ...
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <C
                 onLikeClick={this.onLikeClick.bind(this)}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

I think this is just ugly to do the copy job. Any suggestions? Or am I right about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no right answer here. It depends on why you need two different containers

1. If you want to make data requests on top level you must leave your code as is.
2. If your data request logic will be the same you can hide it and wrap your `C` component in `container` (https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)

like this:

```
class CContainer extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
    // make data request
  }

  render() {
    <C onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />
  }
}
```

and use it in both components A and B

```
class A extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <CContainer />
        ...
    )
  }
}

class B extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <CContainer />
        ...
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeh, i can do that. As to why i need 2 different containers because the 2 containers r located in same route lvl, so they r siblings. And they need different data from database so.

Comment: So i think u prefer me to use the 2nd way, yes?

Comment: If you containers A and B are different routes and needs different data I prefer 1st option. I think this is acceptable. But if component C is independ of the route and needs same data everywhere I prefer 2nd option